# "QuickFix.UnsupportedMessageType" exception was thrown, when the "onMessage" crack was present

Tags: fix-protocol

I'm not quite sure why it happened. I request Market Data Request (with 263=1) and the counterparty gave response with (absolutely) MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh (35=W). I've included the onMessage(QuickFix.FIX42.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh ...) on my message's cracker.. But the app has thrown the exception "QuickFix.UnsupportedMessageType"...

So, I tried to capture the SnapshotMarketData directly from "FromApp" (without Message Cracker) and it successfully done. So what's the matter with my message's cracker? Any idea?

This is the "FromApp" currently..

```
public void FromApp(QuickFix.Message msg, SessionID sessionID) //every inbound Application-level message
    {
        if (msg.Header.GetField(Tags.MsgType) == MsgType.MARKET_DATA_SNAPSHOT_FULL_REFRESH)
            Homepage._homepage.GetFixMessage(msg.ToString());
        else
            Crack(msg, sessionID);
    }
```

And this is the Message Cracker previously (before I capture directly from "FromApp"

```
#region MessageCracker handlers
    public void onMessage(QuickFix.FIX42.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh mdsnapshot, SessionID s)
    {
        Homepage._homepage.GetFixMessage(mdsnapshot.ToString());
    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OnMessage` needs to start with a capital "O".

QF/n uses the C# convention of capitalizing method names.